# Partially schemaless Document overwrites schemaless values

Tags: c#, mongodb, overwrite, schemaless

I have a class in C#, something like:

```
public class MyEntry
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string SimpleHash { get; set; }
    public string GroupIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

now saving this in mongo works as it should. Now I'd like to add some sub-documents to this document. The sub-document's class looks like this:

```
public class Detail
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string DetailHash { get; set; }
}
```

I add those details to the root documents with the Push-command, like this:

```
collection.Update(query, Update.PushWrapped("Details", detail));
```

This works good so far and I have the possibility to read the `MyEntry` without all attached `Details` and I can read all/the first/the last/whichever `Details` I want.
But my problem now is that if I change something in an `MyEntry` and save it, the `Details`-Array is completely deleted.
Is there a way to leave fields not mentioned in a class alone when updating?

Comment: Note that "save" just says "save this entire document" - as explained in the answer, update is what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use update just like you did for the `Detail`. If you just use the native serialization of an entire C# class into a MongoDB collection, you'll overwrite the entire document as you've seen.

```
public class MyEntry
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string SimpleHash { get; set; }
    public string GroupIdentifier { get; set; }
}

var update = Update<MyEntry>.Combine(
    Update<MyEntry>.Set(m => SimpleHash, "TheHash!"),
    Update<MyEntry>.Set(m => GroupIdentifier, "MyGroup"));
```

Then, `Update` the document into the collection using a query, passing the `update` builder object above. (Of course, you can vary the properties as needed). I like this approach better than trying to merge an object, as it means that I don't need to worry about partially loaded C# objects or accidentally removing properties from the MongoDB document because they weren't set.

I'd expect that you may need to add the attribute `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` to your MyEntry class during derserialization or the driver may throw an error when it encounters the unexpected extra data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping to avoid "manually" updating all the properties but it looks like I have to live with it.

Comment: A "merge" just isn't supported.